# Google DFP, Video mid-roll

Tags: ads, google-dfp

I need help with Google DFP integration.

I am using [The Google Media Framework player](https://github.com/googleads/google-media-framework-ios), and I am trying make a campaign(Google DFP) that should show me a mid roll video.

I need make some like [this](http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=640x480&iu=%2F15018773%2Feverything2&ciu_szs=300x250%2C468x60%2C728x90&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=xml_vast2&unviewed_position_start=1&url=dummy&correlator=[timestamp]&cmsid=133&vid=10XWSh7W4so&ad_rule=1). I have access to a DFP Premium account, but I don´t know the correct steps to make a mid-roll in the DFP account. In my searching documentation, I not found nothing.

If any have some idea, it´s good received.

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Ad Rules to do this. Here's more info:

https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1406418